# How to Loop the prompt for user input if it is not a unique value in an ArrayList?

Tags: java, validation, arraylist, input

I am trying to have users input a UNIQUE value for a book's ISBN. 
I am able to receive user input and it populates the ArrayList just fine, but if a user inputs a value that is already in the ArrayList, I want them to receive an error message and be prompted to try again.

```
 do{ 

    System.out.print("\n ISBN must be 4 numbers only.\nEnter isbn: ");
    isbn = sc.nextLine();

  try{
    isbnInt = Integer.valueOf(isbn);
    }//end try

    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
     System.out.println("\nPlease enter integer numbers only.");
    }//end catch


 }while(isbn.trim().length() <4 && (isbn.trim().length()>0) ||  (isbn.trim().length() >4));
    sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println();

 do{   
    System.out.print("Enter quantity: ");
    quantity = sc.nextLine();

     try{
    quantityInt = Integer.valueOf(quantity);
    }//end try

    catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
     System.out.println("\nPlease enter integer numbers from 1 through 1000 only.");
     }//end catch

  }while(quantity.trim().length() > 1000 ||(quantity.trim().length()<0) );
```

Comment: Well, first things first: do you know how to check whether or not a given number is already in the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to validate ISBN such as

```
public boolean verifyISBN(int ISBN)
```

Here you will check if ISBN exists in the arraylist by using a for loop

Upon receiving the return value store it in a variable and use in while condition of 1st do-while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're in need of a different data structure, like HashSet, because it doesn't allow duplicates.

When calling the add method:

```
hashSet.add(quantityInt);
```

It verifies if the HashSet already contains that element.

- if it **contains**: it'll not insert the element and will return **false**;
- if it **doesn't contain**: it'll insert the element and will return **true**.

You can check if the method returned false and if so, show an error message and enable the input again.

```
...
final Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
int quantityInt = scanner.nextInt();
while(!set.add(quantityInt)) {
   System.out.println("You can't insert duplicate elements.");
   quantityInt = scanner.nextInt();
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I am dialing in on it. Unfortunately I am required to use an ArrayList for the assignment.
I have a while loop setup with a boolean operator "contains"

```
while(contains != books.contains(isbnInt)){
```

But it isn't working